Inequality of cardinal sums
Define $|A|<|B|$ iff there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ but there is no injection from $B$ to $A$.
Is it provable in ZF that $|A|<|C|$ and $|B|<|D|$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset=C\cap D$ implies $|A\cup B|<|C\cup D|$? I've tried a proof by contradiction:
Assume an injection from $C\cup D$ to $A\cup B$ exists. Then a bijection from $C\cup D$ to $A\cup B$ exists. But I don't know how to keep going or if the statement is even true.

No. Even $|A \cup B| < |C \times D|$ is not provable: A weak version of König's Theorem - Does this depend on Choice?.

You will have to use the axiom of choice somehow; in the absence of that axiom the cardinals $\mathfrak c$ and $\aleph_1$ could be incomparable, and in that case you would have $$\mathfrak c\lt\mathfrak c+\aleph_1$$ $$\aleph_1\lt\mathfrak c+\aleph_1$$ $$\mathfrak c+\aleph_1=\mathfrak c+\mathfrak c+\aleph_1+\aleph_1$$

Assuming the axiom of choice you can prove that all cardinals are comparable, and the sum of two cardinals is equal to the greater one unless they are both finite. In your problem, unless $A$ and $B$ are both finite, either $|A|+|B|=|A|$ or else $|A|+|B|=|B|$.

@user14111 check the question: the OP wrote "Is it provable in ZF..."

@user14111 But actually, your second comment would make a great answer!
